# PostgreSQL Wildcard number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two attributes in table (char and date) like a 
90061455555 and 1990-06-14.
I must create references where third and fourth number in first attribute (90**06**1455555) are the same as month in date attribute (1990-**06**-14).
and similar:
**90**061455555 19**90**-06-14
9006**14**55555 and 1990-06-**14**

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
where substr(strcol, 3, 2) = to_char(datecol, 'MM')
```